# How can I describe two things that constantly fuel each other? Example in description

Tags: synonyms

The sentence I'm trying to write it

Focusing on xyz, where accomplishments and struggles [blank],

I'm trying to say, that as the person accomplished more, they would face more struggles, and as they had struggles, they actually flipped it into an accomplishment.

Ex: Because somebody was a certain race/religion, they can't buy a house. So the person bought out a hotel and didn't let the oppressing group stay there. (This eventually led to financial growth, etc).

Comment: A **virtuous circle** maybe?

Comment: Could you rephrase that, please? I'm sorry to say that your "house/hotel" example seems not to clarify anything but more to show that the rest of the Question is a lot more confused than clear.

Comment: Sorry for difficulty. To clarify, I'm specifically talking about a family that would face struggles, because people wanted to undermine them, but they turned it into a success.

Answer (score 2):

A couple phrases come to mind:

- "*Feed off each other*" - This is most close to the "constantly fuel each other" construction you used in the title, and would fit right into the `[blank]` in your example. Merriam-Webster has a [page for the "*feed off*" idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feed%20off), and it's commonly used with "each other".
- "*virtuous cycle*" - This is a little different in connotation, but coneys a similar meaning. It emphasizes this cycle being self-reinforcing and having a positive, enriching outcome. It's contrasted with a "*vicious cycle*", another common phrase. This doesn't fit exactly in your example sentence, but might be useful elsewhere. Use these more when reflecting on the nature of the process itself rather than the narrative that the process is part of. See [Wikipedia's page on the two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuous_circle_and_vicious_circle) for many other usage examples.

By the way, "*fuel each other*" is also a completely valid way to describe this.

Comment: You could add ***positive feedback loop***.